# Azure Application Proxy conditional access with linked applications

Tags: azure, proxy, conditional

Linked applications, using AAD pre authentication, are no longer selectable options for my Conditional Access Policies.  Early last week, I was able to add my internal linked applications to conditional access policies, now all of the sudden they do not show up as selectable options. Is anyone else seeing this?

Under Cloud Apps or actions, I only see Cloud Apps, but no longer see applications protected by my application proxy.

Very frustrating because I was able to add on premise apps just last week.

Comment: Hmm... not sure what "linked applications" here mean, but as long as your app is published using AAD App Proxy, or is registered using AAD Enterprise Apps, you should be able to see it in the list of CAP, can you look confirm that your app is registered in AAD? references: 1) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/concept-conditional-access-cloud-apps#other-applications
 and 2) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/view-applications-portal

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack exchange. It's not clear what your actual question is here (and may only solicit "me-too" responses, which are not that useful). Can you rephrase this to ask a question - "How can I" "How do I" "What is".